# Post Method is not working in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create ASP.NET Core Web API. I have Post/Get method as per below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/getProffessionByID/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult getProffessionByID(Int64 id)
    {
        AllProffession model = new AllProffession();
        try
        {
            var result = model.GetAllProffession.Where(i => i.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError("Something Went Wrong : " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/savePerson")]
    private IHttpActionResult savePerson(PersonModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (model.name != string.Empty || model.weight != 0 || model.height != 0 || model.proffession != 0)
            {
                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                Random random = new Random();
                int i = random.Next();
                model.id = i;
                return Ok(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError("Something Went Wrong : " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

My get Method is working all fine from url as well as Postman.
[image]

I've tried [FromBody] As well, but it is also not working

**Model:**

```
public class PersonModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int weight { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public int proffession { get; set; }
    }
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { Controllers = "API", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        }
```

Comment: How does your PersonModel look?

Comment: If I use FromBody in post method, I am getting same error which I have shown in Screenshot

Comment: is `Controllers`  correct? or should it be `controller` in your route config

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers You are mixing up code for core and web api 2. Which is it

Comment: it is ASP.NET Core

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers all the code shown so far is for web api 2

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers you probably need to start a new project and make sure you are using the correct version/framework.

Comment: This is the old way of web api 2 to create api .NET core only have a single controller class and not webapiconfig file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you should change your method to **public** instead of **private**.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/savePerson")]
public IHttpActionResult savePerson(PersonModel model) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: It was silly me to declare method as private. I didn't notice I have written private method. Thanks for help.

Also, thank you Niladri and Nkosi for relealize me that I am going on wrong way. I would start learning ASP.NET core api from starting.